# Why does MySql Workbench not let me see the full grid display. Can't resize

Tags: mysql-workbench

I'm having a problem with MySQL Workbench where it doesn't let me see the full grid for my ER diagram. When I try to resize it stutters and just shows the side bar multiple times. I'm not sure how to describe the problem so here are a few images of what happens. I'm running Fedora Workstation 27 on a Lenovo Yoga 2 pro.

[image: image1]

[image: image2]

[image: image3]

Comment: Which Workbench version is that? If that is the latest (currently 6.3.10) then better file a bug for this, so that it can get fixed for the next release.

Comment: This is for version 6.3.10, I filed a bug report.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem, i found that launching from a terminal after setting the environment varaibale GDK_SCALE=1 solved the problem.

```
export GDK_SCALE=1 && mysql-workbench
```

Comment: this worked!.. but HiDPI displays are not new fangled.. come on mysql - fixed this silly issue

Answer (score 1):

I found a work around. When I change the resolution from 3200x1800 to 1920x1080 it works properly. Also, If I use 3200x1800 and change the scale to 100% it also works.

Comment: The problem only occurs when I have my resolution at something greater than 1920x1080 and don't have it scaled at 100%.

Comment: Please mention that in your bug report as well.

Comment: Your solution helped me a lot ! Please mark it as "choosen answer" to set your question "solved" and possibly help other people to find it :-)